# TemplateException: could not write compiled template - after git clone

Tags: php, lithium

Anyone have any idea why I am getting this exception after getting the latest version of lithium?

```
( ! ) Fatal error:
  Uncaught exception 'lithium\template\TemplateException' with message
  'Could not write compiled template
  C:\Users\Master\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PSER\PSER/resources/tmp/cache/templates/template_views_pages_index.html_0_1344056913_326.php
  to cache.' in
  C:\Users\Master\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\libraries\lithium\template\view\Compiler.php
  on line 81

( ! ) lithium\template\TemplateException:
  Could not write compiled template
  C:\Users\Master\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PSER\PSER/resources/tmp/cache/templates/template_views_pages_index.html_0_1344056913_326.php
  to cache. in
  C:\Users\Master\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\libraries\lithium\template\view\Compiler.php
  on line 81

Call Stack

Time Memory Function Location

1 0.1070 331944 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 0.2013 4387040 lithium\action\Dispatcher::run( ???, ??? ) ..\index.php:41
3 0.2013 4388248 lithium\core\StaticObject::filter( ???, ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Dispatcher.php:155
4 0.2013 4389784 lithium\util\collection\Filters::run( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\StaticObject.php:126
5 0.2014 4391752 {closure}( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Filters.php:183
6 0.2015 4391752 lithium\util\collection\Filters->next( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\cache.php:46
7 0.2015 4391784 {closure}( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Filters.php:202
8 0.2075 4427760 lithium\util\collection\Filters->next( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\action.php:51
9 0.2075 4427792 lithium\action{closure}( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Filters.php:202
10 0.2198 4534776 lithium\core\StaticObject::invokeMethod( ???, ??? ) ..\Dispatcher.php:154
11 0.2198 4534808 lithium\action\Dispatcher::_call( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\StaticObject.php:75
12 0.2198 4535896 lithium\core\StaticObject::_filter( ???, ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Dispatcher.php:265
13 0.2198 4536152 lithium\action{closure}( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\StaticObject.php:119
14 0.2198 4536152 lithium\action\Controller->_invoke( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Dispatcher.php:262
15 0.2199 4537752 lithium\core\Object->_filter( ???, ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Controller.php:198
16 0.2199 4538032 lithium\action{closure}( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Object.php:238
17 0.2199 4538280 lithium\core\Object->invokeMethod( ???, ??? ) ..\Controller.php:184
18 0.2200 4538312 app\controllers\PagesController->view( ) ..\Object.php:165
19 0.2200 4538824 lithium\action\Controller->render( ??? ) ..\PagesController.php:32
20 0.2204 4541320 lithium\net\http\Media::render( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Controller.php:266
21 0.2205 4550368 lithium\core\StaticObject::_filter( ???, ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Media.php:593
22 0.2206 4550616 lithium\net\http{closure}( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\StaticObject.php:119
23 0.2208 4553656 lithium\core\StaticObject::invokeMethod( ???, ??? ) ..\Media.php:590
24 0.2208 4553984 lithium\net\http\Media::_handle( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\StaticObject.php:75
25 0.2208 4555936 lithium\core\StaticObject::_filter( ???, ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Media.php:750
26 0.2209 4556184 lithium\net\http{closure}( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\StaticObject.php:119
27 0.2257 4579800 lithium\template\View->render( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Media.php:746
28 0.2259 4583520 lithium\template\View->_step( ???, ???, ???, ??? ) ..\View.php:328
29 0.2259 4587040 lithium\core\Object->_filter( ???, ???, ???, ??? ) ..\View.php:389
30 0.2260 4587304 lithium\template{closure}( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\Object.php:238
31 0.2260 4587336 lithium\template\view\adapter\File->template( ???, ??? ) ..\View.php:386
32 0.2272 4588624 lithium\template\view\Compiler::template( ???, ??? ) ..\File.php:133
```

I'm pretty sure its not a problem with the slashes (forward or back) in the path. I created a quick little test script that proves forward and back slashes can coexist in a path on windows. The resulting path was:

```
C:/Users/Master/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/PHP Prototyping/PHP Prototyping\ABC\testFile.txt
```

The code sample is below:

```
<?php
    $myFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\\ABC\\testFile.txt';
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die('can\'t open file');
    $stringData = 'Bobby Bopper\n';
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = 'Tracy Tanner\n';
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing Windows is choking on those forward slashes...are those something under your control? Perhaps the new version made changes that break it on Windows?

Comment: The slashes *shouldn't* matter. I'd guess a permissions issue on the directory. Check the permissions on the `resources/tmp` directory.

Comment: @randy the permissions have been set for full control for 'everyone'. Error still occurs.

Comment: @JMM Not much I can do about the slashes. I'm developing on Windows, and I am deploying on Linux. Slashes need to stay the way they are.

Comment: Ok, that's not an error though? Do the forward slashses actually work on Windows? On the linux server, does Lithium generate the paths with just forward slashes, or also backslashes, and if so, do the paths with backslashes work on linux? Are there supposed to be consecutive "PSER" segments of the path: "\PSER\PSER"?

Comment: @JMM I've added an example of how slashes can coexist in a windows environment. Of course, the framework might be doing something extra, but pure PHP is able to handle the mixed slashes it would seem. My code wrote the file just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the templates folder under cache didn't exist.

The directory didn't exist because I didn't add it to source control, since stuff under tmp shouldn't go from dev to prd anyway. The issue with writing to the templates cache was always there, but a recent change to the framework causes php to throw an error instead of black holing the error.

I've added some code to the template/view/Compiler.php to handle creation of the missing directory. The first line of the code block is 68, and was not changed. Similarly, the ending line is not changed so you can compare what got added to what was there before.

```
    $compiled = static::compile(file_get_contents($file));

    $pathIsWritable = is_writable($cachePath);      
    if(!$pathIsWritable){
        $exMessage = ' File not writable. ';
        if(!file_exists($cachePath)) {
            $exMessage .= 'Path to file invalid. ';
            $dirCreated = mkdir($cachePath, 0777, true);

            if($dirCreated) {
                $pathIsWritable = true;
            }
            else {
                $exMessage .= 'Attempt to create the directory path failed.';   
            }
        }           
    }

    if ($pathIsWritable && file_put_contents($template, $compiled) !== false) {
        foreach (glob("{$options['path']}/template_{$oname}_*.php") as $expired) {
```

Comment: Instead of overriding Lithium core code, you can use this snippet in your bootstrap https://gist.github.com/1009460

Comment: @MehdiLahmamB. I'm not sure where I'm supposed to add this code? I know you said to add it to the bootstrap file, do you mean at the bootstrap file in the config folder? or do you mean to add this as a file in the bootstrap folder and reference it in the bootstrap file?

Comment: In config/bootstrap/libraries.php, just after Libraries::add('lithium'), and before adding your app (see corresponding lines in the gist)

Answer (score 3):

Your `resources` directory isn't writable so Lithium can't write compiled templates to `resources/tmp/cache/templates`.

EDIT: Double check as well that the `resources`directory exists, since it shouldn't be versioned in a git repo.

You can use this snippet to create it on the fly, with the right permissions: https://gist.github.com/1009460 (`config/bootstrap/libraries.php`)

Comment: allowed full control for 'everyone'. Problem still occurs.

Comment: @mehlah could you please update your answer to include https://gist.github.com/1009460 this way I can upvote your answer and others can find the solution easily :)

Comment: I change `resources` permission to 777 and the problem was solved: `chmod -R 777 resources`